# Declaration of Pointers in Network simulator 2 (NS2)

Tags: c++, pointers, ns2

I want to declare a pointer in c++:

```
class MyAgent : public Agent
{
private:
    int x,y;
    int* xPtr;
    int *yPtr;
    void add();
public:
    MyAgent(); // Declaration of constructor
};

MyAgent::MyAgent() : Agent(PT_UDP)
{
    xPtr= &x;
    yPtr= &y;
    bind("x_otcl", &x);
    bind("y_otcl", &y);

} 
void MyAgent::add()
{
    Tcl& tcl = Tcl::instance();
    tcl.eval("puts \"From add() \"");
    printf("\nx=%d and y = %d\nx+y = %d\n", x,y,x+y);
    printf("xPtr=%d\n",*xPtr);
    printf("yPtr=%d\n",*yPtr);
}
```

What is the difference between xPtr and yPtr? Is xPtr a pointer? Does the compiler ignore the space? From the results, I figured that both of them are pointers but I'm not sure. I always use the second one (yPtr) for declaration of pointers.

Also please tell me how to bind pointers between c++ and otcl.

Comment: Both `xPtr` and `yPtr` are pointers. The space makes no difference.

Comment: @timrau Thanks for your answer. what about the binding of pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `xPtr` and `yPtr` are pointers to integer. Yes, compilers ignore the space.

To bind an `oTcl` variable (x and y) with C++ variables (`*xPtr` and `*yPtr`), use the following code.

```
Tcl& tcl = Tcl::instance();
tcl.eval("set variable_in_tcl");
variable_in_c++ = atoi(tcl.result());
```

As, I have understand, you are calling the `add()` function which will take the variables `xPtr` and `yPtr` value from `oTcl` script and print the value of variable. So, your code will look as follows:

```
class MyAgent : public Agent
{
private:
    // Use x and y in tcl script

    int* xPtr;

    int *yPtr;

    void add();

public:

    MyAgent(); // Declaration of constructor
};

MyAgent::MyAgent() : Agent(PT_UDP)
{
    Tcl& tcl = Tcl::instance();
    tcl.eval("set x");
    *xPtr = atoi(tcl.result());
    tcl.eval("set y");
    *yPtr = atoi(tcl.result());
}

void MyAgent::add()
{
    printf("\nx=%d and y = %d\nx+y = %d\n", *xPtr,*yPtr,*xPtr+*yPtr);

    printf("xPtr=%d\n",*xPtr);

    printf("yPtr=%d\n",*yPtr);
}
```